# Classified raster images extract infos loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, classification, r-raster

I have 800 classified raster images(7 classes) and each classes from one image needs to be calculated in squaremeters. So far it works with one image but not with the loop. What can I do to solve it?

```
report_files<-list(list of 800 tif files)
    for( i in report_files){
  reportfiles_single<-raster(report_files[i])
  df<-as.data.frame(table(reportfiles_single))
  df2<-as.data.frame(df$Freq*(0.070218*0.070218))
  {report_mean<- df2}
}
```

This piece works for one-and there is an example file: https://ufile.io/rb7tj

```
a<-raster("test060707.tif")
val<-values(a)
table_val<-data.frame(val)
df<-as.data.frame(table(table_val))
df2<-as.data.frame(df$Freq*(0.070218*0.070218))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example with maybe 3 images and provide us with your data? Much easier to explore the problem if we can try run it on our machines. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not correct. You do `for( i in report_files){`, but later on you use `i` as if you had `for( i in 1:length(report_files)){`

Inside the loop you do `table(reportfiles_single)`, whereas in the working code example you have, the equivalent would be `table(values(reportfiles_single))`.

Furthermore, you do not keep any of the results, as you overwrite `report_mean` in each iteration.

So you should really start out by learning how looping works, and first make some simple examples.

Also, are you sure the spatial resolution of your data is about 7 by 7 cm? That is possible, but seems unlikely.

Here is an example of what you might do. I use the `freq` method because it is memory-safe, unlike `table(values())`

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
report_files <- c(f, f, f)

res <- list()
for( i in 1:length(report_files)){
    r <- raster(report_files[i])
    # note the -2 for this example, you probably do not want that with your data
    f <- freq(r, digits= -2)
    cellsize <- prod(res(r))
    f[,2] <- f[,2] * cellsize
    res[[i]] <- f
}
```

Instead of using a loop, you could do:

```
s <- stack(report_files)
x <- freq(s, digits=-2)
```

And multiply with the cellsize later.